# VBA Identical code acts differently, one file autofills columns after the initial import and the other file does not

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have two excel files I inherited. They both import .csv files with 14 columns, though 1 also automatically fills other columns with data while the other doesn't. I don't know where the file is getting the instructions to fill those columns or why it stopped.

This code doesn't work

```
Sub RunReport()

    'Copy and Paste New Data from cvdata
    Dim PDate As Date, DMonth As String, DYear As Long, FilePath As String, Usage As String, nextrow As Long, tablecount As Long, pivotcount As Long, newrows As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long, newnewrows As Long, foundRng As Range, CurrentDay As String, FDate As Date, FMonth As String, FDay As String
        
        
    PDate = DateAdd("m", -1, Date)
    DMonth = Format(PDate, "mm")
    DYear = Year(PDate)
    
    'CLEAR OLD DATA
    Usage = "CVK Usage_" & DYear & DMonth
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Worksheets("CVDataK").Select
    Range("Table2").Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Selection.Delete
    
    FilePath = "N:\Reports\batecuanhuehue\cvdata.csv"

    Workbooks.Open (FilePath)

        'COPY NEW DATA
        Set tbl = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
        tbl.Offset(1, 0).Resize(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, _
        tbl.Columns.Count - 14).Select
        Selection.Copy

        'PASTE NEW DATA
        Usage = "CVK Usage_" & DYear & DMonth
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        Worksheets("CVDataK").Select
        Range("A2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        
    'Clear Clipboard and close File
    Workbooks("cvdata.csv").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWindow.Close
    
    'Refresh All Pivots
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll


    'Update Table Copy and Paste First Column
    
    'Count the number of rows in the selection
    Worksheets("CVUsage1").Activate
    
    Range("A12").End(xlToRight).Select
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    
   'First empty row of table
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Range("T5:AB5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("T5:AB" & lastrow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Resize Range("$AD$4:$Bu$" & lastrow)

    'Clear Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    'Refresh All Pivots
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    
    FDate = Date - 1
    'FDay = Format(FDate, "d")
    'FMonth = Format(FDate, "m")
    CurrentDay = FDate


Sheets("CVUsage1").Select
Set foundRng = Range("AJ:AJ").Find(CStr(CurrentDay), lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
 
If foundRng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Sample Date not found"
Else
    Sheets("Report").Select

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Sample Date").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Sample Date").EnableMultiplePageItems = False
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Sample Date").CurrentPage = FDate
  
End If

    Sheets("Calculations").Select




End Sub
```

This code works properly.

```
Sub RunReport()

    'On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    'Copy and Paste New Data
    Dim PDate As Date, DMonth As String, DYear As Long, FilePath As String, JktntUsage As String, tablecount As Long, pivotcount As Long, newrows As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long, newnewrows As Long, foundRng As Range, CurrentDay As String, FDate As Date, FMonth As String, FDay As String
 
    PDate = DateAdd("m", -1, Date)
    DMonth = Format(PDate, "mm")
    DYear = Year(PDate)
    
    'CLEAR OLD DATA
    Usage = "PlasticK Usage" & DYear & DMonth
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Worksheets("plastick").Select
    Range("Table1").Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Selection.Delete
    
    FilePath = "N:\Reports\batecuanhuehue\plasticdata.csv"

    Workbooks.Open (FilePath)

        'COPY NEW DATA
        Set tbl = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
        tbl.Offset(1, 0).Resize(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, _
        tbl.Columns.Count - 14).Select
        Selection.Copy

        'PASTE NEW DATA
        JktntUsage = "PlasticK Usage" & DYear & DMonth
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        Worksheets("plastick").Select
        Range("A2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    
    'Clear Clipboard and close File
    Workbooks("plasticdata.csv").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWindow.Close
    
    'Refresh All Pivots
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
  
    'Count the number of rows in the selection
    Worksheets("Plastic Usage1").Activate
    
    
   'First empty row of table
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Resize Range("$AA$4:$BK$" & lastrow)

    'Refresh All Pivots
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    Range("A12").End(xlToRight).Select
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Worksheets("Plastic Summary").Activate
    
'ErrHandler:
    'Application.EnableEvents = True
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    
    FDate = Date - 1
    'FDay = Format(FDate, "d")
    'FMonth = Format(FDate, "m")
    CurrentDay = FDate


    Sheets("Plastic Usage1").Select
    Set foundRng = Range("AE:AE").Find(CStr(CurrentDay), lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
 
    If foundRng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Sample Date not found"
    Else
    Sheets("Report").Select

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Sample Date").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Sample Date").EnableMultiplePageItems = False
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Sample Date").CurrentPage = FDate
  
    End If

    Sheets("Calculations").Select


End Sub
```

The .csv files that are imported recently changed to have an additional 14 columns. I added an offset to the import, one file worked properly after that while the other did not.

Comment: Is this what you mean by "I added an offset to the import" -  `tbl.Columns.Count - 14)`. ?

Comment: From this line:  `Range("Table2").Select` it looks like you're using an Excel table and you're deleting the DataBodyRange of that table with the line `Selection.Delete`.  Excel tables can have formula that will automatically copy down as you add new rows.  If you delete all the rows in the table and add new data it remembers the formula and adds them in again.  I think this is where your new data columns are coming from.

Comment: @CDP1802 yes, that's what I meant by adding an offset, that eliminates the rightmost 14 columns from being imported.

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook The worksheet that the data is being imported to is a table called Table2. Importing the .csv data without deleting the Table2 data will cause data repetition. When I select a cell, there's no formulas there, just data. A lot of the cells remain empty, only filling a cell every 26 rows in some case. I just don't know where the file is getting the commands to do that.